# CS:GO Stucks at Loading Screen

Tags: 20.10

Whenever I am opening CS:GO, then it launches in Windowed mode (I also tried changing the Set Launch options, but still opens on Windowed) then the intro comes and it stucks at this page where Operation Broken Fang image comes!

[image: Screenshot of operation broken fang's loading screen]

Comment: Generally for situations like this, it's important to include details like hardware specifications of your computer and how something is being run. That said, if this is being run through Steam, you may have more luck getting a solution on their forums.

Answer (score 1):

I had to switch the game to fullscreen.

- Go to the Steam library
- Right-click on the game name
- Select "Properties"
- In the general tab go to launch options and type "-full"
  [launch options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qm1a.png)

There is also an option to skip intro videos, so additionaly you can try add one more parameter into launch options.

- "-novid"

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me yesterday. There is a "close" button on the right bottom, which let's you close that preview and continue to main menu. Try "Alt" + "Enter" to get to fullscreen or resize the window.

Comment: is this helped you and your Game is working????

Comment: Yes it worked for me, could play the game.

Comment: Bro, it is not working can you pls tell me properly that what I have to do?

Comment: the game is not going in Fullscreen